# how to create the function to calculate diagonal difference

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function to calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonal
the function take the parameter: int arr[n][m] data input is a integer

if input:

```
4 5 1
2 5 6
9 8 9
```

the output is:
3

they are form

```
4+5+9 = 18
1+5+9 = 15
|18-15| = 3
```

```js
function Difference(arr) {
  var n = arr.length;
  var d1;
  var d2;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // finding the sum of primary diagonal         
      if (i == j) {
        d1 += arr[i][j];
      }
      // finding the sum of secondary diagonal         
      if (i + j == n - 1) {
        d2 += arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.abs(d1 - d2);
}

console.log(Difference([
  [4, 5, 1],
  [2, 5, 6],
  [9, 8, 9]
]))
```

after i run this code i get output not a number

Comment: How about initialising d1 and d2 to 0?

Comment: You don't initialise d1 & d2 , try `var d1 = 0;  var d2 = 0;`   Otherwise your first calc is -> `undefined + 4`, = `NaN`..

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a need to check every single value in the matrix!

Comment: Still gives NaN even when d1 and d2 = 0

Comment: @ChrisG It gives 3 when you set them to 0.

Comment: nvm, I didn't see the update on the question on how you actually called your function and how you passed your parameters

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and calculate the index of the anti-diagonal matrix

```js
function difference(arr) {
    let l = arr.length;
        d1 = 0,
        d2 = 0;
      
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        d1 += arr[i][i];
        d2 += arr[l - i - 1][i];
    }
    console.log(d1, d2);
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2);
}

console.log(difference([[4, 5, 1], [2, 5, 6], [9, 8, 9]]));
```

Comment: You could even do way with both `d1` and `d2` by calculating a runnig difference, getting the absolute value at the end.

Comment: @phuzi, right. i would had proof the sums, too.